# Power of The Floor Guardians

Tags: overlord

I know they say that Shalltear was stronger that Albedo, but after the fight between her and Ains, I really saw, just how op her equipment was, despite that, Albedo is the floor guardian overseer, but Ains clearly said that she would lose against her, and because none of the other floor guardians stepped up, I'm curious to know whether or not the manga or light novel gives some sort of indication or chart on levels, stats and list of abilities of the various floor bosses, and any other NPC in the guild base.

Comment: Looking for their respective skills and levels are one thing, but who would win in a battle questions are pure opinion and not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Actually it's not quite a ''who would win in a battle'' question as the data given about shalltear clearly states that she uses Holy skills which, as said by Ains, are a very big advantage against boththe followers of Ains aswell as Ains himself. On the Overlord Wiki there is indeed a ranking in skills such as HP, Physical Atk, defense etc. Based on this Shaltear scores a total of 732 overall whereas Albedo scores 690 overall

See: http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Shalltear_Bloodfallen/Abilities_and_Powers and 
http://overlordmaruyama.wikia.com/wiki/Albedo/Abilities_and_Powers

Comment: @Chen Orihara, with a bit more development your comment can be the answer to this question, i always tought that Albedo was elected Guardian for her better analitical mind, Shalltear is more prone to provocation she has much more pride that Albedo in similar situations showed

Comment: I speculated that floor guardians are guild defense "raid bosses" simply from wondering what their purpose are. They are tasked to guard floors which leads to the top floor of nazarich and so other guilds battle their way to the top floor. The first scene also clarifies my speculation where other players were attacking nazarich and they were defeated at the front. This  is the only acceptable speculation I can think of because how can a guild master not defeat his f*cking minions.